# Calculation of Easter dates in Spark SQL using Databricks & DBT

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, dbt

I'm trying to calculate Easter dates using Spark SQL, but I'm encountering some issues with the syntax. I've attempted to adapt existing SQL code, but it seems that some syntax elements are not supported in Spark SQL.

Here's the SQL code I've been trying to use:

```
WITH years AS (
  SELECT YEAR(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL (ROW_NUMBER() OVER () - 1) YEAR)) AS EasterYear
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 20))) t
),
e AS (
  SELECT
    EasterYear,
    EasterMonth,
    EasterDay,
    DaysToSunday,
    epact,
    paschal,
    DATE_FROM_PARTS(EasterYear, EasterMonth, EasterDay) AS EasterDate
  FROM (
    SELECT
      EasterYear,
      epact,
      paschal,
      TRUNC(3 + (DaysToSunday + 40) / 44, 0) AS EasterMonth,
      DaysToSunday,
      DaysToSunday + 28 - (31 * TRUNC(EasterMonth / 4)) AS EasterDay
    FROM (
      SELECT
        EasterYear,
        epact,
        paschal,
        paschal - TRUNC(MOD((EasterYear + EasterYear / 4 + paschal - 13), 7)) AS DaysToSunday
      FROM (
        SELECT
          EasterYear,
          epact,
          epact - TRUNC(epact / 28) AS paschal
        FROM (
          SELECT
            YEAR(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL (24 + (19 * MOD(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), 19))) * 30 DAY)) AS EasterYear,
            MOD((24 + (19 * MOD(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE), 19))), 30) AS epact
        ) AS epact
      ) AS paschal
    ) AS dts
  ) AS m
)
SELECT EasterYear, EasterDate, 'Easter Sunday' AS HolidayName
FROM e
UNION ALL
SELECT EasterYear, DATE_ADD(EasterDate, INTERVAL -2 DAY), 'Good Friday'
FROM e
UNION ALL
SELECT EasterYear, DATE_ADD(EasterDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY), 'Easter Monday'
FROM e
UNION ALL
SELECT EasterYear, DATE_ADD(EasterDate, INTERVAL 39 DAY), 'Ascension Day'
FROM e
UNION ALL
SELECT EasterYear, DATE_ADD(EasterDate, INTERVAL 49 DAY), 'Whit Sunday'
FROM e
ORDER BY EasterYear, EasterDate
LIMIT 1000;
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the syntax used in the above code is not supported in Spark SQL.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide guidance on how to calculate Easter dates using Spark SQL. Are there any alternative approaches or workarounds that I can use? If possible, could you provide a modified version of the SQL code that is compatible with Spark SQL?

Thank you in advance for your help!